# Survival Analysis - Median Overall Survival

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am trying to run a script to calculate KM median overall survival and progression free survival, but keep getting an invalid 'row.names' length error message.

My data set looks like this:

```
Patient #   PFS     OS     Alive    POD
1           3       5       1        1
2           5       5       1        0
3           17      17      0        1
```

My script is the following:

```
survFitOS <- survfit(Surv(data_set$OS,data_set$Status) ~ 1, data = data_set)
surv_median(survFitOS)
```

I keep getting this error message:

> Error in row.names<-.data.frame(*tmp*, value = value) : 
>     invalid 'row.names' length

Comment: I've searched you posting for clues as to where one might be loading `surv_median` and come up empty. I also doubt that a three-line dataset can support any effort at coding a tested response. Perhaps you should be making an effort at running the example code from the help page where that function is described in whatever unnamed package it lives?

Comment: Also ... `print.survfit` displays a median , so why not use it? And you should not use `$` to access colum names inside the Surv function. It messes up the connections between the `data` argument value.

Comment: You need to specify where these functions are from.  `Surv` and `survfit` seem to be from the `survival` package; `surv_median` appears to be from the `survminer` function.  In addition, your code refers to a column named "status" but this column is not in your provided dataset.  Finally, if you want us to tinker with your code to help you find a solution, you should provide a minimal example so that we can recreate the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want, but I've had to guess at which packages your functions are from and I had to invent a `status` column.

```
df <- data.frame(
    patient = c(1, 2,  3),
    os      = c(5, 5, 17),
    status  = c(1, 1,  0)
)

surv_ojb <- survival::Surv(time=df$os, event=df$status)

survfit_os <- survival::survfit(surv_ojb ~ 1)

result <- survminer::surv_median(survfit_os)
```